# Why do we have an [op-amp] and an [operational-amplifier] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that some recent questions have been tagged with both [op-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/op-amp) and [operational-amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operational-amplifier) (e.g. [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/425157/1)). The former seems to be the main tag (it has a tag wiki and over 4 thousand questions) whereas the latter has no tag wiki and only 111 questions.

There is no need to have two tags for op amps. I suggest we make these two tags either [tag synonyms and/or merge them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/299342). Assuming the community agrees, which should be the master tag?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, done. [operational-amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operational-amplifier) is the master tag, and [op-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/op-amp) is a synonym that maps to it.

Comment: The tag wiki info is gone now, though, since the master tag didn't have any tag wiki info. It looks like the tag wiki info for the synonym is gone now, too.

Comment: That's fixed now, too.

Comment: If the long name is preferred, I suggest the same be applied to [tag:diff-amp] vs [tag:differential-amplifier] and [tag:in-amp] vs [tag:instrumentation-amplifier] (and maybe [tag:instrumentation-amp] for completeness)