# Make [diff-amp] a synonym of [differential-amplifier]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms

We have both [differential-amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-amplifier) and [diff-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diff-amp), with the latter having far more questions than the former (> 100 questions). However, the former is the full, proper name.

Would a moderator kindly merge the two tags and make them synonyms, with [differential-amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-amplifier) the master tag?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: Null - Hi, I have been monitoring your post to see if there was broad agreement. Currently it has 7 upvotes & no downvotes (good!). Also I see that `operational-amplifier` is the master synonym for `op-amp` which seems like a very similar situation to this one (good!). Before going ahead (since merging is very difficult to undo) can you see any *disadvantage* to (a) merging `diff-amp` with master `differential-amplifier` and  (b) making them synonyms? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Indeed, [operational-amplifier] was made the master synonym for [op-amp] [by my suggestion](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6899/51760). I can see no harm in merging them since they refer to the same thing and are used the same way on the site's questions. Furthermore, per main meta [good tag synonyms should be merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/299342). Finally, as a moderator on Science Fiction/Fantasy I've merged/synonymized tags with ease and without issue.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why we should name tags after slang though. Same deal with "op amp".

Comment: @Lundin Generally, no, but [diff-amp] not only had more questions but multiple users watching it -- apparently that slang is common enough to have made the slang version of the tag more popular than the version with the proper name. This way the tag gets remapped to the proper name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As requested and discussed in comments, I've merged [diff-amp] into the master tag [differential-amplifier] with [diff-amp] being a synonym.